# How get value of a list by a tuple in Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, tuples

I have this structure in a tag called items_value:

```
{
    ('prog1','date1'): {
        'total_error': 4256,
        'components1': [{
            'errors': 5,
            'lines': 1
        }],
        'components2': [{
            'errors': 5,
            'lines': 1
        }
    ],
    ('prog2','date2'): {
        'total_error': 4256,
        'components1': [{
            'errors': 5,
            'lines': 1
        }
    ]
}
```

How a get the values inside each tuple in Django? I tried:

```
{% for elem in items_value %}
```

but the result is:

```
('prog1','date1')
('prog2','date2')
```

I want, for exemple:

```
{
    'total_error': 4256,
    'components1': [{
        'errors': 5,
        'lines': 1
    }],
    'components2': [{
        'errors': 5,
        'lines': 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do here? Your example desired output is the value for your `('prog1','date1')` key - it's not clear to me how that relates to your attempt to iterate over the dict. Also, are you working in a template or in Python code? `{ for elem in items_value }` isn't right for either, but `{% for elem in items_value %}` might be.

Comment: I want the dict in each tuple. I'm working in template. I corrected the ask with the %, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over a dictionary gives you its keys. To get its values, iterate over `items_value.values()`. Or, in a template, `{% for value in items_value.values %}`. Note that Python dictionaries are unordered, so there are no guarantees about what order you'll get the values in.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the values:

```
{% for value in items_value.values() %}
```

Comment: Sorry, i see now what you are up to :)

Comment: I used your suggestion and get "Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'items_list.values()'", so I removed the () and works. Thanks